# Return Bool in Alamofire closure

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I use Swift 2 and Xcode 7.1.

I have a function who connect my users, but it will connect at my database with HTTP. I use Alamofire for execute this request. I want to know, from a view controller if the user is connected.

I have my function connect in a class. And i test connection in a ViewController.
Like this :

```
    class user {

    // ...

    func connectUser(username: String, password: String){

        let urlHost = "http://localhost:8888/project350705/web/app_dev.php/API/connect/"
        let parametersSymfonyG = [
            username, password
        ]
        let url = UrlConstruct(urlHost: urlHost).setSymfonyParam(parametersSymfonyG).getUrl()

        //var userArray = [String:AnyObject]()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .responseString { response in

                if let JSON = response.result.value {

                    var result = self.convertStringToDictionary(JSON)!

                    if result["status"] as! String == "success"{
                        let userArray = result["user"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                        userConnect = self.saveUser(userArray)
                    } else{
                        print("ERROR-CONNECTION :\n Status :\(result["status"]!)\n Code :\(result["code"]!)")
                    }
                    return ""
                }
        }
    }

    // ...
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    @IBAction func connect(sender: AnyObject?) {

        // CONNECTION
        User.connectUser(self.username.text!, password: self.password.text!)

        // CHECK
        if userConnect != nil {
            print("connected")
        }else{
            print("NotConnected")
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

**First solution : Return**

To do so would require that my function returns a Boolean.
Only I can not use return.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseString { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                var result = self.convertStringToDictionary(JSON)!

                if result["status"] as! String == "success"{
                    let userArray = result["user"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                    userConnect = self.saveUser(userArray)
                } else{
                    print("ERROR-CONNECTION :\n Status :\(result["status"]!)\n Code :\(result["code"]!)")
                }
                return "" // Unexpected non-void return value in void function
            }
    }
```

**Second solution :**

I can also test if the user has been logged, but before testing, I must wait for the function have finished loading.

```
users.connectUser(self.username.text!, password: self.password.text!)

// after 
if userConnect != nil {
    print("connected")
}else{
    print("NotConnected")
}
```

I would prefer return a boolean. It will facilitate the processing.
Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest employing a completion handler in your `connectUser` method:

```
func connectUser(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // build the URL

    // now perform request

    Alamofire.request(url)
        .responseString { response in
            if let json = response.result.value, let result = self.convertStringToDictionary(json) {
                completion(result["status"] as? String == "success")
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
    }
}
```

You can then call it using:

```
users.connectUser(username.text!, password: password.text!) { success in
    if success {
        print("successful")
    } else {
        print("not successful")
    }
}
// But don't use `success` here yet, because the above runs asynchronously
```

---

BTW, if your server is really generating JSON, you might use `responseJSON` rather than `responseString`, further streamlining the code and eliminating the need for `convertStringToDictionary`:

```
func connectUser(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // build the URL

    // now perform request

    Alamofire.request(url)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let status = dictionary["status"] as? String {
                completion(status == "success")
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
    }
}
```

If you've written your own server code to authenticate the user, just make sure you set the right header (because `responseJSON` not only does the JSON parsing for you, but as part of its validation process, it makes sure that the header specifies JSON body; it's good practice to set the header, regardless). For example in PHP, before you `echo` the JSON, set the header like so:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: What if I want to do the same for `responseCollection`? I didn't find a way. Please Help!

Comment: @iRiziya - Yes the idea is the same. Whenever you're dealing with an asynchronous method with a completion handler, just repeat the process, employing a completion handler in your own method.

Answer (score 2):

The completion handler of your `Alamofire.request` method is asynchronous and it doesn't have a return type specified in its signature. Thats why you see an error when you provide a `return` statement in your completion handler closure.

You will have to split your request and response processing to separate methods and call the response processing method instead of using `return` statement.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseString { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            var result = self.convertStringToDictionary(JSON)!

            if result["status"] as! String == "success"{
                let userArray = result["user"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                userConnect = self.saveUser(userArray)
                processSuccessResponse() //Pass any parameter if needed
            } else{
                print("ERROR-CONNECTION :\n Status :\(result["status"]!)\n Code :\(result["code"]!)")
                processFailureResponse() //Pass any parameter if needed
            }
       }
}

func processSuccessResponse() {
    //Process code for success
}

func processFailureResponse() {
    //Process code for failure
}
```

Comment: My function is in a class. How to put this in place? (see my edit)

Comment: If you have it separate classes, refer to the solution provided by @Rob. Thats the best option.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of doing this is to call a function in the completion handler. You can also set a boolean flag in order to check if the user is connected at any given time.

```
func connectUser(username: String, password: String, ref: MyClass) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
        .responseString { response in

            var userIsConnected = false

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                var result = self.convertStringToDictionary(JSON)!

                if result["status"] as! String == "success"{
                    let userArray = result["user"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                    userConnect = self.saveUser(userArray)
                    userIsConnected = true
                } else {
                    print("ERROR-CONNECTION :\n Status :\(result["status"]!)\n Code :\(result["code"]!)")
                }

            } else {
                print("Response result nil")
            }

            ref.finishedConnecting(userIsConnected)
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
    var userIsConnected = false

    func startConnecting() {
        connectUser(username, password: password, ref: self)
    }

    func finishedConnecting(success: Bool) {
        userIsConnected = success

        ... post-connection code here
    }
}
```