# Retrieving data from Firebase does not work

Tags: swift, firebase

I have this code below in order to retrieve a list of restaurants and their data. However, it's not storing the data, and every time I try to return the array it returns nil. But if I print it, prints the data. Any suggestions?

```
func getRestaurants()-> Array<Restaurant>{
    var baruri = [Restaurant]()
    dataBaseRef.child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print(snap)
                if let restaurantData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let restaurant = Restaurant(restaurantData: restaurantData)
                    baruri.append(restaurant)
                    print(baruri)


                }
            }
        }
    })
    return baruri
}
```

Comment: I do not have experience with firebase. But from what I see, it looks like the call to retrieve the list of restaurants could be an asynchronous call and return is called before the block inside `.observe` is executed. If that is the case, use a completion handler block to post back the retrieved data. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121289/return-bool-in-alamofire-closure/34121496#34121496) might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

The firebase `observe` is an asynchronous callback function, so it will run after it is finished. In other words, your `return baruri` will always runs before the value got back. You can use completion handler to get the value you want.

```
var restaurants = [Restaurant]()

func getRestaurants(completion: @escaping (Array<Restaurant>) -> Void){
    var baruri = [Restaurant]()
    dataBaseRef.child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print(snap)
                if let restaurantData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let restaurant = Restaurant(restaurantData: restaurantData)
                    baruri.append(restaurant)
                    print(baruri)

                    completion(baruri)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

// Call this function with call back 
getRestaurants { restaurants in
    self.restaurants = restaurants
}
```

Comment: how would I store that data in a variable somewhere else? let temp = RestaurantData().getRestaurants()