# Swift 3 and Alamofire send method as parameter

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am new at swift and I got problem with requests. I want to send diffrent methods to a function, which will return a string, but I don't how to do it. I tried this way, but I got

> Error with wrong type of .post and return of function makeWebServiceCall

Could somebody help me?

```
public func login(userName: String, password: String) -> [String:Any]{

let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
return makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest)

}

private func makeWebServiceCall (urlAddress: String, requestMethod: String, params:[String:Any]  ) -> [String:Any] {

Alamofire.request(urlAddress, method: requestMethod, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

   if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
```

**Edited:**

[image]

Comment: Alamofire.request is asyn call. so use closures .

Comment: Ok, I think I found how to make return, but still I got a problem with sending .post to request as function parameter, what can I do?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121289/return-bool-in-alamofire-closure

Comment: Thank you, you answered my first question, but also I need help with method, sometimes I want to send .post request and sometimes .get request to the function how I can do that?

Comment: pass .get in requestMethod when you need get request and .post for post.

Comment: And requestMethod type should be string?

Comment: I tried, but still get some error, I added pictur, if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestMethod` type should be `HTTPMethod`

```
private func makeWebServiceCall (urlAddress: String, requestMethod: HTTPMethod, params:[String:Any]  ) -> [String:Any] { ... }
```

Comment: this is what I need